# Translate inertia tensor, caculate distance matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I know that inertia tensor of a sphere is

$$
2mr^2/5\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now if I translate it into a coordinate (x,y,z). What will be the inertia tensor then ?

All I know is, after translation :

$$I_{new}=I_{old}-m*r^2$$ and here $r$ is a matrix, actually I want to know how can I calculate that matrix ?

Comment: The variable $r$ is a distance. See "http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/parax.html#pax"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the parallel axis theorem in vector/tensor form

$$ \mathbf{I}_{\rm new} = \mathbf{I}_{\rm old} + m \left[ \matrix{y^2+z^2 & -x y & -x z
\\ -x y & x^2+z^2 & - y z \\ -x z & - y z & x^2+y^2 } \right] $$

where $\pmatrix{x\\ y \\z}$ is the location of $({\rm old})$ relative to $({\rm new})$.

For an example, see the end [of this related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/519864/392)  (equation 4).

Comment: can you tell me why [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/505273/242367), how the value of r came here, it's a 3*3 matrix, where you have given me a 1*3 matrix

Comment: You mean how $$ -\left[ \matrix{0 & -z & y \\ z & 0 & -x \\ -y & x & 0} \right] \left[ \matrix{0 & -z & y \\ z & 0 & -x \\ -y & x & 0} \right] = \left[ \matrix{y^2+z^2 & -x y & -x z
\\ -x y & x^2+z^2 & - y z \\ -x z & - y z & x^2+y^2 } \right] $$ ? In that post $r$ is a 3×1 vector and $\tilde{r}$ is a 3×3 matrix. The overbar denotes the cross product matrix operator.